# Как проксировать все запросы на index.php без изменения URL на базе NGINX

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, проксирование

Столкнулся с проблемой перенаправления всех url на index.php без перезаписи для дальнейшей обработки классом маршрутизатором в php.

**Пример:** `http://localhost/public/page/`

**Результат в php при запросе $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']:** `/public/page/`

**Что пробовал:** rewrite и с флагами, и без, не особо помог, он меняет url.

**Структура проекта**

Контейнеры:

[image: 1]

Часть кода файла **default.conf** (NGINX):

[image: 2]

Comment: >не особо помог, он меняет url.
Так и пусть меняет url - сохраняйте где-то оригинальный url, либо в заголовке, либо в параметре запроса. А уже на стороне php вы вольны заполнить REQUEST_URI чем хотите. Да и потом - точка входа: fastcgi_param    SCRIPT_NAME  - переопределите её на статичную, и у вас всегда будет фиксированная точка входа php - тогда и не надо менять REQUEST_URI, так как он останется оригинальный.

Comment: Ах вот оно как, чутьё подсказывало, не прислушался, спасибо большое!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо [Гончарову Александру](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/213977/%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80) за помошь, вот такой default.conf получился)

```
server {
    listen ${NGINX_PORT};

    root /app/public;
    index index.php;

    server_name ${NGINX_SERVER};

    access_log /var/log/nginx/${NGINX_SERVER}.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/${NGINX_SERVER}.error.log;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @mod_rewrite;
    }

    location @mod_rewrite {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?$1;
    }

    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}

server {
    server_name "~^www\.(.*)$";

    return 301 $scheme://$1$request_uri ;
}
```

Comment: а зачем вам все же перенаправление на index.php? Написали бы уже try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args; - и получали бы любой запрос не соответствующий имеющимся файлам или каталогам в корневой index.php с аргументами, если они были переданы.